# Invalid nonce in twitter request

Tags: c#, twitter

Ive been battling with the oAuth flow for a while with my twitter app. I finally got my access token granted, and now i cant call the twitter update url without getting an 'invalid nonce' error, yet im building and signing the URL in the exact same way as when calling the request and access token methods. Has anyone else had this problem, and do you know how to solve it??

Comment: Are you generating a new, unique nonce for each request? All messages with the same timestamp must have a different nonce.

Comment: yes im calling a getNonce method every time i generate a new signature on a new URL and it works perfectly fine all the way up to getting the access token. After that trying to call any of the post methods is just returning a 401 error. I have no clue what is causing this because i dont know why it work fine through each of the other steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i figured out that query strings get cut off after a certain length. So instead of using a web client to do all my work, i switched to web request and used the 'content' for the parameters instead, this appears to have fixed the problem!